# How to overcome Class name clashing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

Given this code

```
import UIKit

class Configuration{
    static var name = "test"
}

class MyButton: UIButton{
    func test(){
        let name = Configuration.name // Type 'UIButton.Configuration' has no member 'name'
    }
}
```

Is there a way to reference the `Configuration` class from inside the MyButton class instead of the (new to iOS 15) nested struct `Configuration`

Of cause just renaming the Configuration class here would be an easy fix, but I'm curious as to if there is another way to handle this.

Comment: @MartinR With the RC beta? That's weird. I have no trouble reproducing the phenomenon by copy and paste.

Comment: @matt: You are right. I had tested it with Xcode 12.

Comment: @MartinR So easy to do when you've got multiple Xcodes sitting around...!

Comment: One way is to declare the Configuration class inside the MyButton class, at least if the Configuration class is only meant to be used together with MyButton.

Comment: another to put MyButton and Configuration into an enum declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app target is a module, which has a name. (Look in the app target build settings to find out what it is.) Use that to namespace the class:

```
let name = MyApp.Configuration.name...
```